# How to check the contents of the head section

Tags: javascript, html, proxy

I wrote a proxy server which adds a comment tag to the HEAD-section of each page.
Now I want to determine in a JavaScript file if the comment is present there.

How do I accomplish that?

Here's an example page:

```
<html>
  <head><!-- page is proxified -->
    <title>Hello proxified world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       // What to do here?
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var comment = '<!-- page is proxified -->',
    commentPresent = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML.indexOf(comment) !== -1 ? true: false;

if (commentPresent) {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jquery:

```
var headContents = $('head').html();
```

Javascript:

```
var headContents = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, which doesn't have an `innerHTML` property. Do you mean `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML`?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but a little bit fiddly, to read comment nodes with Javascript.  You'd have to find the head element, then loop through its child nodes to find one which is a comment (node.nodeType == 8) or as others have pointed out, get the whole head.innerHTML and regexp it.

However, it may be a bit easier to achieve this by adding in some other element, such as a meta element (which also goes in the head) and then you can access it more easily with getElementsByTagName() and/or jQuery, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure. But comments are not written in the DOM. So it should be impossible to get it by xpath or something else.

You could fetch the whole content of the html tag by

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head').innerHTML;
```

and apply a regexp.

An other possibility could be to add an meta tag. This could be retrieved with js a little bit easier.

Comment: Might need to be 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;